# Command line to search for all word files using wildcards in filename

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe, dir

How can I find all files that have a name like `ALPS*.doc` in a folder like `P:\Systems\A.L.P.S\`?

I tried this using the command line but it returns zero:

```
Systems\A.L.P.S>dir /s /b c:\ |find /c "\ALPS*.doc"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly specify what to list in the directory from the dir command itself.

So you would use this command:

```
cd /d c:\
dir /s /b ALPS*.doc
```

You first navigate to the root, then search recursively from there.

Do note that searching from C:\ will only find results in C:. If you want to search in P:\Systems\A.L.P.S, you of course have to search from that folder. the first line would then be:

```
cd /d p:\Systems\A.L.P.S
```

Comment: thanks, so is there a way of just getting a count of all the files with a name like `ALPS*2013*.doc` ?

Comment: is there a way of counting all the files without listing them, or do I have to output them to a (text) file?

Comment: If you do not care for the filenames, you can ommit the /b which gives a detailed result including the filesize per file, but also a summery at the end stating how many files were found and what its size is.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use this command: dir /s /b ALPS*.doc | find /c "ALPS" assuming ALPS is not written twice in the name.

Answer (score 0):

Within Powershell.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\ -Recurse "ALPS*.doc"
```